# trying to implement Quicksort Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Just started learning algorithms: trying to implement the quicksort algorithm with Java. But it's not showing anything in the output tried many times but unable to find the reason.
It is not showing anything.

```
public class Try {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int []arr= {22,9,8,45,28,7,1};
        int len = arr.length;
        quicksort(arr, 0, len-1); 
        for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }

    static void quicksort(int [] arr, int low, int high) {
        if (low < high) {
            int index = partition(arr, low, high);
            quicksort(arr, low, index -1);
            quicksort(arr, index+1, high);
        }
    }

    static int partition(int [] arr, int low, int high) {
        int pivot = arr[low]; 
        int i = low;
        int j = high;
        while(i<=j) {
            while(arr[i]<pivot) i++;
            while(arr[j]>pivot) j--;
        
            if(i<=j) {
                // swapping i with j 
                int temp = arr[i];  
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
            //swapping pivot(low) with j when i<j 
            int temp = arr[low];
            arr[low] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
        return j;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is not showing anything?"  It has to at least print?

Comment: Have you checked if a "hello world" program shows anything?

Comment: its not giving any output I don't know why tried a lot

Comment: That isn't a bad idea actually.  Try printing "Starting Sort..." at the very beginning of your code, just in case the trouble is that you aren't seeing the output.

Comment: Yes I have written a lot of programs all of them are working but this isn't

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Besides the link by Hulya, I think now is a great time to learn how to use a debugger.  What IDE or environment do you use to run code?

Comment: usually I use eclipse for coding

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php

Comment: If you have a working "hello world" program, change it bit by bit to your quicksort program and see where it stops working.

Comment: You application stuck in `partition` method in `while` loop. You need to debug that why it is iterating over and over

Comment: Main issue: get rid of that second swap using `low` - it's not needed and makes no sense. Also, `while(i<=j) {` can be `while(i<j) {` and `if(i<=j) { ... swap ...` can be `if(i<j) { ... swap ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the partition method. You keep getting stuck in the second while loop. You should do it with a single loop, here's an exemple ( I personally prefer using a for loop ) :

```
int pivot = arr[high];  
int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element and indicates the 
                   // right position of pivot found so far

for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
{
     // If current element is smaller than the pivot
     if (arr[j] < pivot)
     {
         i++;    // increment index of smaller element
         int temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[j];
         arr[j] = temp;
     }
 }
    int temp = arr[i + 1];
    arr[i + 1] = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp;
    return (i + 1);
```